# Using Dynamic library Load returns another result

Tags: c, dll

i have an issue using DLL, i have a code that encrypt strings, buf using dll the result of the function changes.

CODE:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>



int cantidad(char *s){
    int max=0;
    for (int i = 0; s[i] ; i++) {
        max=i;
    }
    return max+1;
}

char* pascal(char *s) {
    //char s1[cantidad(s)];
    int cuociente;
    char *s1=calloc(strlen(s)+1,sizeof(char));
    strcpy(s1,s);
    if (s == NULL){ //caso que sea nulo.
        return NULL;
    }
    cuociente=cantidad(s)/2;
    if(cantidad(s)%2==0){//par
        for (int i = 0; i <cuociente-1 ; i++) {
            if(i%2==0){ // iteracion impar debido a que esta parte siendo iteracion 1,
                s[cuociente-2-i]=s1[cantidad(s)-1-i];
                s[cuociente+1+i]=s1[i];
            }
            if(i%2!=0){// iteracion par
                s[cuociente-2-i]=s1[i];
                s[cuociente+1+i]=s1[cantidad(s)-1-i];

            }

        }

    }

    if(cantidad(s)%2!=0){//impar
        for (int k = 0; k <cuociente-1 ; k++) {
            if (k%2==0){ //iteracion impar
                s[cuociente-2-k]=s1[cantidad(s)-1-k];
                s[cuociente+2+k]=s1[k];
            }
            if (k%2!=0){ //iteracion par
                s[cuociente-2-k]=s1[k];
                s[cuociente+2+k]=s1[cantidad(s)-1-k];
            }
        }
    }
    printf("%s",s);
    return s;

}
```

Using CLion and terminal, if i encrypt "btvenyz tnyvn" the function returns "teytnyz bvvnn" that its the expected result.
But if i use makefile and DLL:

MAKEFILE:

```
all: shared compile

shared:
    gcc -c -Wall -Werror -fpic ./lib/pascal.c
    mkdir ./sym
    gcc -shared -o ./sym/libpascal.so pascal.o

compile:
    mkdir ./bin
    gcc -Wall -Werror main.c -o ./bin/hash -ldl
    rm -r *.o

clean:
    rm -r ./sym ./bin
```

MAIN WITH DLL:

```
int main(){
    char palabra[256],seq[256];
    char (*func_pascal)(char[]);
    void *handle_pascal;
    char *error;
    //PREPARE LIBRARY
    handle_pascal= dlopen("../sym/libpascal.so",RTLD_LAZY);

    // ERROR
    if(!handle_pascal){
        fprintf(stderr, "%s \n", dlerror());
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    dlerror();

    func_pascal = (char (*)(char[])) dlsym(handle_pascal,"pascal");

    error = dlerror();
    //ERROR
    if(error != NULL){
        fprintf(stderr,"%s \n", error);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
//INPUT
    fgets(palabra,256,stdin);
    fgets(seq,256,stdin);
    printf("STRING: %s\n",palabra);
    for (int i = 0; seq[i]; ++i)
    {
        if (seq[i]=='P')
        {
            (*func_pascal)(palabra);
            printf("ENCRYPTED WORD:%s\n",palabra);
        }
    }


    return 0;
}
```

Using DLL the output is:

INPUT

```
btvenyz tnyvn
P
```

OUTPUT

```
STRING: btvenyz tnyvn

ynevt
z bnvyntENCRYPTED WORD:ynevt
z bnvynt
```

Originally there are several encryption codes, where only this one generates error in the output, so I would like to know what I am doing wrong and how to solve it, thank you very much!

Comment: Probably not the problem but this produces undefined behavior. You need:
`*(void **) (&func_pascal) = ....` to be standard compliant.

Comment: There are lots of things wrong here. For example what does `cantidad` do (it seems it's a (worse) `strlen`).

Comment: solved, the problem was fgets (), I changed the way to get a string and it worked in all the places I compiled, the only thing is that i do not understand why fgets () causes the issue. thanks1

Comment: Guess you didn't realize that `fgets` returns the line-terminating character (`LF`, `0x0A`, `\n`) too.